# Question about meaning of "What did you come up with?"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Which of the following meaning is true for this sentence:
1. What happend to you uexpectedly?
2. What did you do unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2):

What did you come up with?

I think this question conveys neither of the senses presented by the 0P.

The meaning of the idiom "come up with" is very clear in a dictionary.
It means to find, think of something needed such as a reply, a sum of money, an idea, or a plan. A few examples are given below:

.This is the best answer he came up with.

.She has come up with a good scheme to double her income.

.I wanted to buy the house, but I couldn't come up with the cash.

.Doctors haven't come up with a cure for the disease.

.He asked me to come up with some new ideas.

"What did you come up with" may mean "What did you find or what did you think of?

Answer (score 0):

*Come up with* is ordinarily used to report the outcome of a fairly long effort, typically a literal or figurative search:

> After half an hour's Googling I **came up with** this answer.
>   I've been thinking about this problem over the weekend, and I **came up with** an approach I think might work.
>   Kevin's been running some simulations and has **come up with** some interesting results.

So *What did you come up with?* will ordinarily mean

> What did you find that is/was useful?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for certain without any context, but it sounds like you were supposed to invent something (e.g. a new slogan or song), and now the deadline has passed you are being asked what you made.

> "We're all excited to see your new proposal! What did you come up with?"

The phrase can also be used if you're telling a story where you had a problem, and someone asked how you solved it.

> "I was trapped in the woods and didn't know how I was going to eat!"
>
> "Oh no! What did you come up with to survive?"

Less commonly, "come up in/came down with" is a phrasal verb meaning to get ill (usually with  a visible symptom such as a rash)

> "I had to see a doctor after that I'd come up in hives on my arm!"
>
> "That's awful, did the doctor say what was wrong? What did you come down with?"